# Fast query become super slow into a procedure

Tags: postgresql-11

I have a problem on a query, that for privacy reasons I can't show you (however I'll provide you the execution plan).
The problem is that, when I execute this query outside a stored procedure, it's quite fast (20 sec for over 70.000 rows), but when i execute it into a stored porcedure it becomes super slow (5 minutes for the same data). How is this possible?
What can I try to do to improve this performances?

I've already tried to change the condition of execution of this query by changing it in a dyanamic form and putting it into a temporary table but the performances did not change.

```
Subquery Scan on t  (cost=16149.34..16152.92 rows=53 width=775) (actual time=4978.471..5382.467 rows=77616 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=11847, temp read=6433 written=6439
  ->  Unique  (cost=16149.34..16151.86 rows=53 width=711) (actual time=4978.465..5268.859 rows=77616 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=11847, temp read=6433 written=6439
        ->  Sort  (cost=16149.34..16149.47 rows=53 width=711) (actual time=4978.464..5139.298 rows=171110 loops=1)
              Sort Key: HIDDEN_TABLE1.aaa, HIDDEN_TABLE1.bbb, HIDDEN_TABLE1.ccc, HIDDEN_TABLE1.ddd, HIDDEN_TABLE1.eee, HIDDEN_TABLE1.rrr, HIDDEN_TABLE1.jjj, HIDDEN_TABLE1.contract_element, HIDDEN_TABLE1.hhh, HIDDEN_TABLE1.lll, HIDDEN_TABLE1.abc, (sum(HIDDEN_TABLE1.original_amount) OVER (?)), HIDDEN_TABLE1.uuu, (sum(HIDDEN_TABLE1.amount) OVER (?)), (max(HIDDEN_TABLE1.posting_date) OVER (?)), HIDDEN_TABLE1.qqq, HIDDEN_TABLE2.ttt, (CASE WHEN ((COALESCE(HIDDEN_TABLE1.asdf, '0'::numeric) = '0'::numeric) AND ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.gfd)::text <> 'YTD'::text)) THEN '1'::numeric WHEN ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.gfd)::text = 'YTD'::text) THEN CASE WHEN (COALESCE(fx2.uyt, '0'::numeric) = '0'::numeric) THEN '1'::numeric ELSE (fx1.uyt / fx2.uyt) END ELSE HIDDEN_TABLE1.asdf END)
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 25896kB
              Buffers: shared hit=11847, temp read=6433 written=6439
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=16144.51..16147.82 rows=53 width=711) (actual time=2394.118..3317.757 rows=171110 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=11847, temp read=3196 written=3199
                    ->  Sort  (cost=16144.51..16144.64 rows=53 width=645) (actual time=2394.081..2785.327 rows=171110 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: HIDDEN_TABLE1.aaa, HIDDEN_TABLE1.bbb, HIDDEN_TABLE1.ddd, HIDDEN_TABLE1.rrr, HIDDEN_TABLE1.jjj, HIDDEN_TABLE1.h, HIDDEN_TABLE1.hhh, HIDDEN_TABLE1.uuu, HIDDEN_TABLE1.qqq, HIDDEN_TABLE2.ttt, HIDDEN_TABLE1.lll, HIDDEN_TABLE1.abc
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 25568kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=11847, temp read=3196 written=3199
                          ->  Gather  (cost=1590.77..16142.99 rows=53 width=645) (actual time=13.657..503.346 rows=171110 loops=1)
                                Workers Planned: 2
                                Workers Launched: 2
                                Buffers: shared hit=11847
                                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=590.77..15137.69 rows=22 width=645) (actual time=19.160..283.159 rows=57037 loops=3)
                                      Hash Cond: ((((HIDDEN_TABLE1.lll)::text || 'LEA'::text) = (fx2.cod_scenario)::text) AND ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.abc)::numeric(18,0) = fx2.cod_periodo) AND ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.qqq)::text = (fx2.cod_valuta)::text))
                                      Buffers: shared hit=11847
                                      ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=300.18..14830.75 rows=22 width=640) (actual time=7.164..206.819 rows=57037 loops=3)
                                            Hash Cond: ((((HIDDEN_TABLE1.lll)::text || 'LEA'::text) = (fx1.cod_scenario)::text) AND ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.abc)::numeric(18,0) = fx1.cod_periodo) AND ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.uuu)::text = (fx1.cod_valuta)::text))
                                            Buffers: shared hit=11616
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=9.58..14523.82 rows=22 width=635) (actual time=0.166..111.711 rows=57037 loops=3)
                                                  Hash Cond: ((HIDDEN_TABLE1.field_x)::text = (HIDDEN_TABLE2.field_y)::text)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=11363
                                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on HIDDEN_TABLE1  (cost=0.00..14510.62 rows=905 width=130) (actual time=0.013..67.993 rows=145561 loops=3)
                                                        Filter: (((uuu)::text <> (qqq)::text) AND ((COALESCE(booking_type, 'JOURNAL'::character varying))::text = 'JOURNAL'::text) AND ((measure)::text = '-'::text))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 5918
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=11197
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=9.57..9.57 rows=1 width=1042) (actual time=0.081..0.082 rows=11 loops=3)
                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=104
                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.27..9.57 rows=1 width=1042) (actual time=0.049..0.076 rows=11 loops=3)
                                                              Buffers: shared hit=104
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on HIDDEN_TABLE2  (cost=0.00..1.24 rows=1 width=1032) (actual time=0.017..0.020 rows=11 loops=3)
                                                                    Filter: (((setting_field_x)::text = 'VVVVVVV'::text) AND ((active)::text = 'Y'::text))
                                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=3
                                                              ->  Index Only Scan using pk_conto on conto c  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=33)
                                                                    Index Cond: (cod_conto = (HIDDEN_TABLE2.field_y)::text)
                                                                    Heap Fetches: 33
                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=101
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=154.67..154.67 rows=7767 width=22) (actual time=6.931..6.931 rows=7767 loops=3)
                                                  Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 484kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=231
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on HIDDEN_TABLE_3 fx1  (cost=0.00..154.67 rows=7767 width=22) (actual time=0.012..1.413 rows=7767 loops=3)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=231
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=154.67..154.67 rows=7767 width=22) (actual time=11.962..11.962 rows=7767 loops=3)
                                            Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 484kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=231
                                            ->  Seq Scan on HIDDEN_TABLE_3 fx2  (cost=0.00..154.67 rows=7767 width=22) (actual time=0.005..5.334 rows=7767 loops=3)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=231
Planning Time: 2.465 ms
Execution Time: 5395.802 ms
```

I would like to bring the execution time similar to the query executed outside the stored procedure.

Comment: Could you please clarify your text content? It will be easier to understand

Comment: Without the query and the procedure that uses the query this is impossible to answer. The plan shows that the query only takes 5 seconds (not 20 seconds or 5 minutes) so I guess it's the _processing_ of the data that is slow, not the query itself

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the real code, but here you can find the query with hidden field and table name, hope you can understand. Thanks a lot.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JbpieQ71ikJVN1LZ83L8z095Qqm4GAonFH1Y4oyTMAc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And I can't share the stored procedure but I can say that it uses 2 temporary table (HIDDEN_TABLE1, HHIDDEN_TABLE3) to do the query and it will insert the rows into another temporary table